# How to extract the live price, price change, and percentage change from yahoo finance using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I need to scrape data for over 2000 tickers using data that can be found on this page: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL. I was able to get the code down for the volume, bid price, etc., but have been struggling with getting the ticker, live price, percent change, and change.

I inspected the html structure and currently have this code, but I end up not getting the data that I need (everything was NA). I don't completely understand how else to approach analyzing the html structure and how to pick out the correct parts to get what I need. I would really appreciate some insight. Thank you!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define the URL
`url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL'

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Extract the price
price_element = soup.find('div', {'data-field': 'regularMarketPrice'})
price = price_element.text.strip() if price_element else 'N/A'

# Extract the live price
live_price_element = soup.find('fin-streamer', {'data-testid': 'qsp-price'})
live_price = live_price_element.text.strip() if live_price_element else 'N/A'

# Extract the change
change_element = soup.find('fin-streamer', {'data-field': 'regularMarketChange'})
change = change_element.text.strip() if change_element else 'N/A'

# Extract the change percent
percent_element = soup.find('fin-streamer', {'data-field': 'regularMarketChangePercent'})
percent_change = percent_element.text.strip() if percent_element else 'N/A'

# Print the extracted data
print('Price:', price)
print('Live Price:', live_price)
print('Change:', change)
print('Percent Change:', percent_change)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
import yfinance as yf
aapl = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah I got it working using yfinance but the problem is that I need this to run for a lot of tickers and there's a limit on the number of requests you can make to the API. That's why I was trying to go down the webscraping path.